# How to use Filter SearchView for RecyclerView when using Livedata?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have a `RecyclerView`. I want to make it filterable with SearchView. My application is based on `Android Architecture Components`.

I created a filter method for `searchView` .When i search something it's work but when i clear text from `searchView` ,list do not change and still shows search data.

**Activity:**

```
    private StudentAdapter mAdapter;

    mAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //ViewModel
    StudentViewModelFactory factory = new StudentViewModelFactory(mDb, mClassId);
    StudentViewModel viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(StudentViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getStudentEntries().observe(this, studentEntries -> mAdapter.setStudents(studentEntries));

    //SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText){
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
    }
    });
```

**Adapter:**

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.itemHolder> {

    private List<StudentEntry> mStudentEntries;
    private List<StudentEntry> filteredStudentEntries;

    public StudentAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setStudents(List<StudentEntry> studentEntries) {
        this.mStudentEntries = studentEntries;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setPerformances(List<PerformanceEntry> performanceEntries) {
        this.mPerformanceEntries = performanceEntries;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
        .
        .
        .

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mStudentEntries = (List<StudentEntry>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                filteredStudentEntries = null;//avaz shod vali test nashod
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredStudentEntries = mStudentEntries;
                } else {
                    filteredStudentEntries = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
                }


                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredStudentEntries;
                return results;
            }
        };
    }

    protected List<StudentEntry> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {
        List<StudentEntry> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (StudentEntry item : mStudentEntries) {
            if (item.getStudentName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)
                    || item.getStudentId().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                results.add(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate.. for answer refer this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350291/how-can-fillter-the-recyclerview/57354872#57354872

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can fillter the recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350291/how-can-fillter-the-recyclerview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change :**

```
private List<StudentEntry> filteredStudentEntries;
```

**To :**

```
private ArrayList<StudentEntry> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

**And Change :**

```
public void setStudents(List<StudentEntry> studentEntries) {
    this.mStudentEntries = studentEntries;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**to :**

```
public void setStudents(List<StudentEntry> studentEntries) {
    this.mStudentEntries = studentEntries;
    arrayList.addAll(mStudentEntries);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**And change filter method :**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
            mStudentEntries.clear();
            if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                mStudentEntries.addAll(arrayList);
            } else {
                for (StudentEntry item : arrayList) {
                    if (item.getStudentName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint)
                            || item.getStudentId().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint)) {
                        mStudentEntries.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = mStudentEntries;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

And don't forget to implements `Filterable` in adapter class.

Comment: Check my edit, I'm working with this. Remember to implement `Filterable` inside your `Adapter`. I hope I've changed code correctly (table names) for your case.

Comment: your way is doesn't work too, my problem is i get list from `LiveData` so i don't have access to list after changed it  @SkypeDogg

Comment: You have two lists. One contains all your data, second one keeps search results. Everytime you search something, you're doing this on List 1 (with all data) and then copy results to List2. That means one of them (List1) always have the same data and the second one changes everytime you search for something. I found there only `filteredStudentEntries = mStudentEntries;` where you just copy reference of your list, what means you work with the same list. If you clear your `search view` the `size()` of list is 0 and then `if` is triggered and it's copying reference to List1 and then you work on it

Comment: what's mean `myIssueList`?

Comment: I found solution(need a stable list) and edit your answer. Thank you for your help.  @SkypeDogg

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I've customized my solution to your case. Seems I missed one list.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below answer it will help,
Search text will pass to recyclerView by below code.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
```

Then RecyclerViewAdapter class should implements **Filterable**

```
public class DashboardRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

//constructor loads data to dataList
      DashboardRecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<Object> data,Context context)
     {
            this.context = context;
            this.dataList = data;   
            this.filteredDataList = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
            this.filteredDataList.addAll(dataList);
        }

    //override this method, it gets the SerchText and then compares with dataList
    @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    ArrayList<Object> filteredDataList_temp = new ArrayList<>();
                    String charString = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();

                    if (charString.isEmpty() || charString.trim().length() == 0 ) {
                        filteredDataList_temp = dataList;
                    } else {
                        for (Object row : dataList) {
                            FoodDetail r = (FoodDetail) row;
                            if (foodName.contains(charString)) {
                                    filteredDataList_temp.add(row);

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = filteredDataList_temp;
                    return filterResults;
                }


               @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                    if (filteredDataList != null) {
                        filteredDataList.clear();
                        filteredDataList.addAll((ArrayList<Object>) results.values);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();   //once completed Then RecyclerView updated with only searched List
                    }

                }
            };

    }
```