# How to set Text in SearchView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, searchview

how to passing data to searchview? I was passing data but I don'n know how to get the value in my searchview, please help me

```
public static final String EXTRA_ID = "Id";

@BindView(R.id.svDetail)
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView svDetail;
@BindView(R.id.rvDetail)
RecyclerView rvDetail;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail_member);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    String id = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ID);
    svDetail.setQuery(id,false);
```

and when I use TextView like // tvdetail.setText(id); 
it's working, why is not working for SearchView? Help please

Comment: `svDetail.getQuery(...)` – Did you mean `setQuery()`, `set` instead of `get`?

Comment: String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id"); will return your id which you passes to SearchView

Comment: I was change to svDetail.setQuery(...), but its not working too

Comment: String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id"); how to get id to searchview? like autofill

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"? Is it crashing? Is it setting something unexpected? Is it just not setting anything?

Comment: when I use TextView like // tvdetail.setText(id); it's working, why is not working for SearchView?

Comment: @yesiaPlorina I have updated the below code, And tried, it is working now, please let me know in case of concern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can fillter the recyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57350291/how-can-fillter-the-recyclerview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to check that you are getting the data in your **`Intent`** , like below:-

```
       /// GETTING INTENT DATA
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.hasExtra("EXTRA_ID")) {
            String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
              YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.setActivated(true);

                YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.onActionViewExpanded();
                YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.setIconified(false);
                YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.clearFocus();


 ///AT THE END YOU NEED TO SET THE TEXT
                YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.setQuery(id,false);

        }
        else {
            Log.e("NO DATA","NO DATA FOUND");
        }
```

One more issue it can be that You are passing data **`Integer`** value and getting **`String`** and it can be vice-vera

Comment: when I get data with TextView , Its working, why It not working with Searchview? final String idku = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_ID);
        tvdetail.setText(idku);

Comment: @yesiaPlorina I have updated the code above, added the `YOUR_SEARCHVIEW.clearFocus()` at the end of the line..Try it and let me know once

Comment: E/AudioMixer: AudioMixer::getTrackName out of available tracks
 E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
 E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
com.yesia.searchrecyclerview E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
com.android.inputmethod.latin 
com.yesia.searchrecyclerview E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: @yesiaPlorina What is this? is it  a new issue?

Comment: @yesiaPlorinan Please check the updated solution and let me know once

Comment: Let me check at my end, will let you know soon

Comment: @yesiaPlorina I have updated the above code, And it is working now, please try once again, and let me know in case of concern

Comment: Not possible, yet now i have used the full code and it is working fine.Have u used above code ??

Comment: I think you just need `searchView.onActionViewExpanded();` only

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to passing data to searchview

but just as a suggest : you can use a editText and just put a search icon to side it

whit editText you can use this code :

```
 EditText searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);

    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "editText content changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

and for passing value just write `searchBar.setText(id);` ; this line runs the TextChangedListener and now you have a text change listener for your search bar too